# How to display a value in a Label

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I try to make in a `Form` a `label` to display the free space from C:/ drive and d:/ drive and for this I have the next code :

```
private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var drive = new DriveInfo("c");
      long freeSpaceInC = drive.TotalFreeSpace;

      var drive1 = new DriveInfo("D");
      long freeSpaceInD = drive1.TotalFreeSpace;

      label3.Text = "There is " + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInC) + " free in C: and " + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInD) + " free in D:";
}

private static string toReadableSize(long size)
{

     if (size < 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
        return Math.Round(((float)size / (1024 * 1024)), 2) + "MB";

     return Math.Round(((float)size / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)), 2) + "GB";
}
```

It's ok to have `label3_Click` ? it's necessary to have an event ? How I can display that value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on when you want to display it. If you want to display on label click, You will have to assign this click as click event handler to label. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553231.aspx).
Also you will need to assign label.text as

```
label3.Text = "There is " + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInC) + " free in C: and " + toReadableSize(freeSpaceInD) + " free in D:";
```

More from comments : 
Double click on form in design mode, it will create Form1_Load event. Put your code from label3_Click in it.. Your code is working fine.

Comment: it doesn't work,on this +toReadableSize(freeSpaceInC) I have a next error: "Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.

Comment: and I don't need an event, I need just to put those values in that Form

Comment: Did you put assignment to label3.Text and add semicolon at end? If yes, please post update code. Then you can do in on form load. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: in your link it's just a static variable

Comment: I don't know how to modify in another way. I you have an idea please write the cod, I will be so thankful

Comment: why do you have to use the click event? why not on page_load? so as soon as the page loads it will populate the lable

Comment: as I said i don't need the click event .... you can give me an concrete answer, please ?

Comment: Double click on form in design mode, it will create Form1_Load event. Put your code from label3_Click in it.. Your code is working fine.

Comment: If this solved your problem, you can mark it as answer.